# Is there a useful "reference" that can be acquired from a std::function back to the stored function/lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

In C if one wants to know/acquire a useful reference back to a callback/some other function, it can be done quite easily be casting the function to a `void*`. Later, in debug for example, the pointer be examined and traced back to the original function (again as an example, via the compiler map output or even the in editor debugger).

This sort of information is very useful when using "breadcrumbs" - eg. a circular buffer of `void*`s - to debug the flow of an application.

In C++ with `std::function`, it is possible to get a raw pointer via the `target<func_type>()` member function, however this only works if you know ahead of time the precise type of the stored target (i.e. a standard C function), however when storing lambdas this is no longer the case as the target is not longer a simple `void()` for a `std::function<void()>` and will therefore return `nullptr`.

The above being the case, what is the next best reference once can get to the stored target such that it can be used, preferably, after the execution of the application has finished or while execution is paused with the debugger attached?

Alternatively can the target be acquired via some template magic, while still retaining the semantics/usability of `std::function` within the library code? This would need to include capturing lambdas and pure C functions

A few notes:

- I am **not** asking how to do debugging
- I am **not** asking how debug information could be captured from within the stored target - imagine this is a library rather than client code

Comment: Yes you can use templated code to specialize by return type of a function (or a lambda). So maybe you should rephrase your question not in terms of std::function (solution) but in terms of what you want to do (real question).

Comment: Use template argument, so you don't need to care about the type

Comment: Your restrictions are unclear.  What code you can touch and what code you cannot.  And, I mean, in a debugger I can personally see where the std function callback goes.  It looks to me like you have some specific technique you use and don't know how to.do this specific technique with new tools?  And you know how to map a void pointer to a location in a dll, but can't figure out how to duplicate this with std function?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I know the technique I want to use, and as you mentioned doing this in C is relatively straightforward but not so with std::function. The debugger is great when you know when you want to pause, but if you need to find out retroactively how you got somewhere the debugger does not necessarily help. I don't really have any particular restrictions as the library and client code is for myself but I don't really want to be pushing responsibility for debugging outside the library code

Comment: Pepijn Kramer, armagedescu are you suggesting along the lines of:

Comment: Having a struct with both a void pointer and a std::function as members and a constructor of which might look something like `template<typename T> FuncStore(T obj) : ref( &obj ), fn( obj )`? This does appear to solve the issue for a lambda and pure C functions, but there appears to still be an issue if a std::function is passed

Comment: I mean, std function isn't magic.  You can write a clone of it that stores the line number, function and file name of where it was initialized with a lambda, function object or function pointer, (and the address if and only if it was a function pointer).

Answer (score 0):

A `std::function` implements a [template method called `target`()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target) that retrieves a pointer to the underlying type. That's pretty much all you can get from a `std::function`.

Note, that you must know what the underlying, erased type, that's in the `std::function`. This is fundamental to C++: the type of all objects must be known ***at compile time***. There are no workarounds to this, there are no magic types that get instantiated at runtime, depending on some runtime conditions. You cannot declare a pointer of some kind, and have it pop into existence, at runtime, as a pointer to a function, or a pointer to a lambda, or some other thing, depending on what's in the `std::function`. This goes down to immutable fundamental principles of what C++ is, and how it works.

> or while execution is paused with the debugger attached

Nothing special needs to be done to that effect. If paused before invoking a `std::function`, your debugger shouldn't have any issues stepping into the type-erased function call, step by step, and show you where it comes out. Whether or not your debugger can display the virtual objects tucked away in the `std::function` depends entirely on your debugger's capabilities, but the underlying type information is there, and should be inspectable in a debugger.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it appears you have missed the point of the question - I already mentioned that I am not interested in how to debug, and this includes pausing execution. I already mentioned in the question that I know what target is and what it does. I am specifically looking to know the thing that was called - saying I called a std::function is not good enough

Comment: I may be looking at the trace of what was called potentially minutes after the fact or even after the program has crashed

Comment: Unfortunately, once the program has "crashed", all bets are off. A crash is a result of undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means anything could've happen, such as memory corruption, so any "trace" that's part of the process itself, is unreliable. And, before the function gets called, `target()` is all there is to work with, for the reasons that I explained. There are no other answers. `std::function`, and all other parts of the C++ library are defined by the C++ specification, and the C++ specification provides only `target()` as the means of getting at the contents of a `std::function`.

Comment: All bets are not off - there are many ways to debug, the debugger is not the only way. In the absolute worst case I could ask the user of the library to print to the console everytime the function they passed to the library is called. And on the point of crashes undefined behaviour is one possible way a crash occurs, there are also controlled crashes (i.e. a file does not exist that should, so a decision to allow a crash is made), among others

Comment: Another thing to note is that there is a massive difference between the act of debugging and the act of gathering quality information to facilitate debugging

Comment: Cool, so the only thing that can be done here is to use `target()` to collect the required information that's needed, for later analysis, if you prefer to avoid debugging. Do you have a question how to use `target()`? If so, you're welcome to post another question explaining what's unclear about this template.

Comment: Please read the question - `as the target is not longer a simple void() for a std::function<void()> and will therefore return nullptr.`

Comment: Correct, and that's what `target()` will return. A pointer. Did you read the reference page that I cited? Which part of it is unclear to you?

Comment: It is not that it is not a pointer, and it is not that it is unclear - it is not useful

Comment: Well, that's it as far as standard C++ goes, there's nothing else there. It's possible that your compiler offers non-standard C++ library extensions, which might include some implementation-specific feature of this kind, as a non-standard extension. I never heard of anything like that, but that doesn't mean that it doesn't exist. If you [edit] your question and specify which operating system and compiler you're using, there's a very small chance that someone who's more familliar with your specific platform might have more suggestions. But you asked about standard C++, and this is it.